# Laravel 10 Disable OPTIONS Method

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have developed web application using Laravel 10 and nginx, I want to allow only post method for specific route

`Route::post('/otpgen', 'App\Http\Controllers\controller@otpgen')`;

I have following code in my app\Exception\Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return abort(404);
        }
        
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

[image]

as allowed method is POST, for all other request method like HEAD,GET,DELETE i am getting 405 method not allowed response code which is correct, but as you can see in image for OPTIONS method i am always getting 200 instead of 405, I want 405 for OPTIONS method too.

Comment: OPTIONS is for cors. Disable cors - and i think all will be fine.

Comment: @Maksim, thanks for comment, any hint on how to disable CORS ?

Comment: Comment cors middleware in HttpKernel. But this is not good thing, after this your app cannot work with modern browsers.

Comment: @Maksim, it is VAPT finding that unsecure HTTP method OPTIONS is allowed, they want me to disable it

Comment: I think, this is not good point of security analysis.

Comment: @Maksim, yes ..by the way i have handled it at nginx level